# alternative solution to convert PDFs to JPG

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, centos, ghostscript

I've run my course with ImageMagick and Ghostscript.  I left it alone to get on with other areas of development and for the entire day I've been trawling forums trying to get ImageMagick to work on my CentOS server and am now at a point where I could cry with frustration......

Is there a less flaky solution to simply convert an all text PDF into a jpg thumbnail so I can get this headache over and done with?  Nobody seems to know what "Postscript Delegate Failed" means and I don't know how many times I'm meant to install, remove, reinstall, `./configure`, `make`, `make install`, `tar`, feather, hang, draw and quarter Ghostscript and all the devel libraries...  how difficult can it be to convert a PDF to a thumbnail?????

Help!! Please!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.  forget about trying to get [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to convert your PDFs.  I've spent months on this and never found a solution.

So instead do this.

Use `gs` directly to convert the PDF file to a jpeg.

```
exec("gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o $tmp_image -dJPEGQ=95 $pdf_name 2>&1");
```

with the tmp_image in place you can then run the ImageMagick `convert` app

```
exec("convert -colorspace RGB ".$tmp_image." -geometry 80x80 -quality 100 ".$thumb_image." 2>&1");
```

remembering to `unlink($tmp_image);` to stop clutter.  You should have your converted PDF

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS?

```
 /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer --help
Usage:
  evince-thumbnailer [OPTION...] <input> <ouput> - GNOME Document Thumbnailer

Help Options:
  -h, --help             Show help options

Application Options:
  -s, --size=SIZE
```

It produces PNG's; easily converted. The `-s SIZE` option seems to represent the *minimum* dimension, preserving aspect-ratio. (A US Letter sized file at `-s 128` for me produced 128×166 px PNG.)

It's in the `evince` package.

Comment: I just installed and tried it and it gives no error messages, but it also gives no thumbnails either :(

Comment: Sounds like perhaps there are bigger problems afoot there … does `rpm -q --verify evince` show the package and dependencies are installed properly? Is the output filename you passed in a directory without write permissions? Works for me on ( CentOS 5, Fedora 15, Fedora 16 )…

Comment: I yummed it - yum install evince.

Comment: Found something else though....  By using gs directly I've managed to get the all text PDF to convert, but does anyone know which option to give gs to specify a maximum dimension?  The PDF in question is 1040x3700 and I want it to be a maximum of 80px for the thumbnail...  Some PDFs could be wide or tall so I need a maximum stat.

Comment: Perhaps there's a permissions-related issue or similar? I presume your user has read permissions on the input and `rwx` permissions on the directory to contain the output (and `rx` on the path to that directory), &c (the usual suspects)?

Comment: I believe `gs -g`*width*`x`*height* should work with the PNG & JPEG output "devices"? (e.g. `gs -g80x80 `...)

Comment: @Roger990: GhostScript comes with a lot of excellent [documentation](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.04/Use.htm). Have you read it?

Comment: @Martin : No I haven't.  In the real world of development there can be times when you just don't have the ..... well.... time to troll through pages of other peoples documents.  that's what these forums are for.  to ask questions and get answers for the things that you don't have time to find out by any other means

Comment: @BRPocock : It appears that gs doesn't like to scale well and imagemagic handles it via some external mechanics.  I've found that simply converting the image to a like for like jpeg then using imagemagick to do the rescale conversion gave me the desired results.  yay!!! another task on the list to sign off

Comment: @Roger990: Well, this site is no excuse for ignoring RTFM. `;-)`